# Manhua/manhwa about a fox spirit actress in an arranged marriage

Tags: story-identification, manga

There's this ad, I guess, that I accidentally clicked on. There is a fox spirit, the leading lady, and the spirit of the leading man is what I can't remember.

There is an agency they are in as a spirit and they are on Earth so they have to be in human form and act as humans. The leading lady is a famous actress, but the agency who arranges the marriage of each spirit always fails as the leading lady always gets away with it/escapes it and always makes an excuse. But then one day they found a great match and both are on same tricks.

Then there are times that the leading lady, a fox spirit, transforms into her true self, a cute fox, and looks for her arranged husband but then she can't transform back, I don't know nor recall why. However the leading man/her arranged husband said "you remind me of someone", "you're so cute, I'll keep you" not knowing it's his wife.

Comment: Can you screenshot the advert?

Answer (score 1):

Is this ***[I'm Being Shipped With the King of Film!](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/im-being-shipped-with-the-king-of-film)***...?

> What?! The Spirit Management Agency assigned me a husband AGAIN?! And this one's a film mogul! Oh gosh~ I'm just a little fox who's barely come of age... What am I going to do with a thousand-year-old husband~?

The female lead is a young actress and a fox spirit. There's an agency which arranges marriages for beings such as her, and she's told that she's due to meet her third potential husband, who turns out to be a film mogul. During his first conversation with her, he correctly guesses that she's a fox spirit. She wonders what his spirit form is, but it isn't revealed initially. A bit later, he somehow makes her fully transform into a fox, says she's cute, then picks her up and starts petting her.

[image]